# MJML Layout is very buggy in Outlook client but ok in other clients

Tags: email, outlook, mjml

I have used MJML to create 2 different email layouts, one with one button and another one with 2 buttons.
These emails look very good in most clients (webmails, gmail, outlook web, ...) But in the outlook client it looks very bad.

I read that width="" is not that well supported going from MJML to HTML for Outlook, so we deleted the width parameter everywhere in MJML. Apart from that we use nothing out of the ordinary in our emails.

This is the MJML:

```
<mjml>
      <mj-body background-color="#f2f8f9">
        <mj-section background-color="#77c5d5" padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
          <mj-column vertical-align="top">
            <mj-image src="https://www.goomlandscapes.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/logo-placeholder.png" alt="logo" align="center" border="none" width="200px" padding-left="0px" padding-right="0px" padding-bottom="10px" padding-top="10px"></mj-image>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
        <mj-section background-color="#FFFFFF" padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
          <mj-column vertical-align="top">
            <mj-text align="center" color="#1a5966" font-size="28px" font-weight="bold" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px" padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="15px">Welkom bij WebsiteName</mj-text>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
        <mj-section background-color="#FFFFFF" padding-bottom="20px">
          <mj-column vertical-align="top">
            <mj-text align="left" color="#000000" font-size="18px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px">
              <span style="color:#000000">Dag John,</span>
            </mj-text>
            <mj-text align="left" color="#000000" font-size="15px" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif" padding-left="25px" padding-right="25px">
              Bedankt om te registreren bij ons. <br/>
              Je profiel is aangemaakt en klaar voor gebruik. Je kan inloggen met je emailadres: {{email}}.<br/><br/>
              Met vriendelijke groeten.
            </mj-text>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
        <mj-section background-color="#FFFFFF" padding-bottom="20px">
          <mj-column vertical-align="top">
            <mj-button align="center" href="https://www.google.be" font-size="18px" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF" border-radius="12px" border="2px solid #D9E9EB;" color="#000000" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Doe iets!</mj-button>
          </mj-column>
          <mj-column vertical-align="top">
            <mj-button align="center" href="https://www.google.be" font-size="18px" font-weight="bold" background-color="#FFFFFF" border-radius="12px" border="2px solid #D9E9EB;" color="#000000" font-family="open Sans Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif">Doe iets!</mj-button>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
        <mj-section padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
          <mj-column>
                <mj-image src="https://3263vihaxx3jy9zn2ikegau7-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/footer-bg-placeholder.jpg" alt="footer"></mj-image>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
        <mj-section padding-bottom="0px" padding-top="0">
          <mj-column vertical-align="middle">
            <mj-social font-size="14px" icon-size="25px" mode="horizontal">
              <mj-social-element name="facebook" href="xyz"></mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element name="instagram" href="xyz"></mj-social-element>
              <mj-social-element  name="linkedin" href="xyz"></mj-social-element>
            </mj-social>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
        <mj-section>
          <mj-column>
            <mj-text align="center" font-size="10px" padding-top="0">Copyright 2021 - WebsiteName. Alle rechten voorbehouden.</mj-text>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
      </mj-body>
    </mjml>
```

The preview in MJML looks like this:
[image: mjml preview]

So the HTML this generates is put into our system and send via SendGrid.
The resulting email looks like this in Outlook:
[image: email preview outlook]

What is happening for this email to look so bad in Outlook client? (it also looks similarly bad in Windows default Mail client)

Comment: Here’s what I get when I send the HTML generated from the mjml code you posted: https://app.emailonacid.com/app/acidtest/MyFtMGl6PkQv2qHIT7WArRlaiJ6XlmYgCIPUjMUl8Q3l8/list Does this happen when directly sending to Outlook or when you forward an email to it?

Comment: apparently it only happens on email forwards!

Comment: Testing an email by forwarding is usually a terrible idea because you'll forward the email transformed by your email client. (So if your forward from Gmail to Outlook, Gmail will remove all the styles it doesn't support before forwarding.) Here’s a blog post about it: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/why_forwarding_emails_is_so_bad/

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it gave me a lot of insight

Comment: A really good source of email HTML information is HTeuMeuLeu; you got lucky that he answered and his is a complete answer here. A really good source of MJML information is https://mjml.slack.com. Lots of MJML expertise shared there, usually promptly.